# Seaborn Plot showing only legend header and Annotation not in place for only 1 plot in FacetGrid Plot

Tags: python, annotations, seaborn, legend

First time using seaborn plots and managed to come out with the plot i want however there is issue as annotation in only 1 plot(row1,column8)is not in place and legends only show the variable but not the line/color example.

Do assist if you know of the solution or any issues with the code

Dataframe

```
       State  Count  Month  Year
  0       AK   2988      1  2005
  1       AK   2734      2  2005
  2       AK   3055      3  2005
  3       AK   2981      4  2005
  4       AK   3434      5  2005
         ...    ...    ...   ...
  1226    WY    849      8  2006
  1227    WY    723      9  2006
  1228    WY    600     10  2006
  1229    WY    572     11  2006
  1230    WY    585     12  2006
```

Code

```
q3plot = sns.FacetGrid(q3, col="State",col_wrap=(8),hue="Year",sharey=False, sharex=True, legend_out=True)
def f(x,y, **kwargs):
    ax = sns.pointplot(x,y,**kwargs)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        ax.annotate(str(y.values[i]), xy=(x.values[i]-1, y.values[i]),fontsize=6,
                    xytext = (0,10), textcoords="offset points",
                color=kwargs.get("color","k"), 
                bbox=dict(pad=.9,alpha=0.2, fc='none',color='none'),
                va='center', ha='center',weight='bold')
q3plot.map(f, "Month","Count").add_legend()
```

[Current Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA3H3.jpg)

edit:

````
    x = data[x_col]
    y = data[y_col]
    z = q4c["AirportOrigin"]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.annotate(str(z.values[i]), xy=(x.values[i]-1, y.values[i]), fontsize=3,
                     xytext=(0, 10), textcoords="offset points",
                     color=kwargs.get("text_color", "k"),
                     va='center', ha='center', weight='bold')

g4 = sns.catplot(kind='point', data=q4c, x="id", y="TotalDelay", hue="TailNum", palette='spring',
                col="TailNum", col_wrap=4, height=5, aspect=1.7, sharey=False, sharex=False, legend_out=True)
g4.map_dataframe(do_annotate2, 'id', 'TotalDelay', text_color='navy')
plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 1):

Calling `sns.FacetGrid()` directly usually isn't needed.  Things work easier when the more custom `sns.catplot()` is used. (The missing annotations for `DC` seem to be related to a missing year.)

Here is how the code would look like using `sns.catplot()`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def do_annotate(x_col, y_col, data, color, **kwargs):
    x = data[x_col]
    y = data[y_col]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.annotate(str(y.values[i]), xy=(x.values[i]-1, y.values[i]), fontsize=6,
                     xytext=(0, 10), textcoords="offset points",
                     color=kwargs.get("text_color", "k"),
                     va='center', ha='center', weight='bold')

states = ['AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS',
          'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NV',
          'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY']
# first create some test data somewhat similar to the givens
q3 = pd.DataFrame({'State': np.repeat(states, 12 * 2),
                   'Count': np.random.randint(100, 5000, len(states) * 12 * 2),
                   'Month': np.tile(range(1, 13), len(states) * 2),
                   'Year': np.tile(np.repeat([2005, 2006], 12), len(states))})
q3 = q3[~((q3['State'] == 'DC') & (q3['Year'] == 2005))] # remove one year for DC

g = sns.catplot(kind='point', data=q3, x="Month", y="Count", hue="Year", palette='spring',
                col="State", col_wrap=8, height=2.6, aspect=1.7, sharey=False, sharex=True, legend_out=True)
g.map_dataframe(do_annotate, 'Month', 'Count', text_color='navy')
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot with kind='point']

Comment: this works well ! Thanks for the help !!

Just wanting to ask which of the code is used to define the annotation value on the point, as i have another similar graph but the annotation i wanted to put on the point is neither x nor y value

Comment: Calling `g.map_dataframe(do_annotate, 'Month', 'Count', ...)` would use 'Month' for x and 'Count' for y.  You can also modify `do_annotate` to directly decide which columns to plot.

Comment: sorry just realise my question is misleading and incorrect. What i wanted to was to annotate on the x,y point but the annotate text is something else, which is another variable

Comment: In the custom `do_annotate` there is a line `plt.annotate(str(y.values[i]) ...)`. You can change that to what you need. Note that `data` will be the dataframe filtered to only the data that belong to one subplot.

Comment: i try changing the str to the data frame value but it only annotate on the first plot. Is there any additional code needed to rectify this ?

Comment: You need `plt.annotate()` inside `do_annotate`.  Via `g.map_dataframe(do_annotate, ...)`, the function `do_annotate` is called once for every subplot. Each time seaborn sets the "current ax" to the subplot that will be updated.  Maybe you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71660108/edit) your post and add an example of the latest code you tried?

Comment: i edited the post and included it, the only thing i did is to define`z= variable for annotation` and make it str(z.values[i]). Not very verse in python plotting as i started from R programming using ggplot

Comment: Maybe you want `z = data["AirportOrigin"]`? `data` would be `q4c` reduced to only the current subplot.  Does the code give an error message?